# Hardware design a 3 binary numbers adder

Tags: binary, hardware, hardware-design

I want to design a binary full adder to add 3 binary numbers , 
a typical cell of this adder would look like this

[image: schematic]

Can someone explain why we have 2 carries to the next bit ? 
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a particular formula: `0b11 + 0b11 + 0b11 == 0b1001`.

The schematic of this would look like:

[image: schematic]

Adder 0 has the following properties:

- Normal inputs can total to at most `0b11`.
- Carried inputs should always be `0b00`.
- The maximum output is `0b11` (One carry bit, one output bit).

Adder 1 has the following properties:

- Normal inputs can total to at most `0b11`.
- Carried inputs can total to `0b01`.
- Maximum output is `0b100` (Two carry bits, one output bit).